# Check if a matrix contains another matrix

Tags: c

I'm trying to find pattern in a image (the type of image is not important).

In my code, the image is an array where any pixel is given by:

```
(x * y.length + y)
```

At the moment I can't get the code to work because almost everytime it finds 0 occurrences..

So here it's current code:

```
int search_pattern(PPMImage * img, PPMImage * patt)
{
    int cont = 0, i, j, k, p, tmp;

    //iterate image
    for(i=0; i <= (img->x - patt->x); i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j <= (img->y - patt->y); j++)
        {
            tmp = 0;
            //iterate pattern
            for(k = 0; k  < patt->x; k++)
            {
                for(p = 0; p < patt->y; p++)
                {
                    PPMPixel * image_pixel = getPixelPPM(i + k, j + p, img);
                    PPMPixel * pattern_pixel = getPixelPPM(k, p, patt);
                    tmp += cmp_pixel(image_pixel, pattern_pixel);
                }
            }
            if(tmp == (patt->x * patt->y))                  
                cont++;
        }
    }

    return cont;
}
```

I know the error is in the iteration itself because everything else is correct.

```
Info:

...->x is the x length of the image
getPixelPPM  returns the pixel in the given place
cmp_pixel returns 1 if the 2 pixels are equal (not important how) and 0 if not
```

More strange is that if I try using the pattern image as both of the images, I get 1 occurrence but if I try with a valid image I get 0. 
Again, I'm 100% sure that external factors aren't the error.

Thank you.

Comment: Looking fastly at your function I find it correct! But to speed it I'll break the k and p for loops immediately if cmp_pixel returns 0!

Comment: The code you show doesn't seem to have any obvious problems. I would suggest testing it with a 1x1 pattern along with an image made entirely of that colour. If you don't get `img->x * img->y` as the result step through the code in a debugger to see where it deviates from the expected result. If it works with a 1x1 pattern try a 2x2 pattern and go from there until you find a case where it doesn't work.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini  Thank you for the reply... Yes I had the code with that "option" but I changed temporarily...

Comment: @Sergio Formiggini: Note the two outer loops go to `<=`. Which means in the case of the same sized image and pattern the two outer loops just go through once each as they should.

Comment: Yes I see! I deleted my uncorrect comment!!!

Comment: @uesp Yap, that's right... I think this code is right but I can't find the bug here..

Comment: The problem might be in the cmp_pixel function! What is the method you use to extract the pattern? I had similar problems with pattern extracted with graphic tools those patterns seem to contain the right pixel, but they are only similar!

Comment: Since the code you've shown looks fine its going to be hard for anyone to give you a definitive answer without access to all the code and data. Logic would seem to say that if the shown code looks fine then the problem may lie in the code/data not shown. I would start with a 1x1 pattern/image and find the smallest/simplest example that doesn't work and debug from there.

Comment: To prove your code works I created dead-simple proxies for all your unknown code (`PPMImage`, `PPMPixel`, `getPixelPPM()` and `cmp_pixel()`). It seems to work fine for a few trivial test cases. Either your  version of these don't work correctly or you have incorrect interfaces to them in your code. For example, does `cmp_pixel()` really take two pointers to pixels or just values, or does `patt->x * patt->y` overflow because your type of `x` and `y` is too small?

Comment: So I guess I was wrong and the bug must be somewhere else... I will get all the steps checked and then I'll post my feedback here...
Thank you all!

Comment: Speaking from experience, the best thing you can do when trying to hunt down a bug is to remove as many assumptions as possible about what you *think* the code is doing. Its far to easy to look at a piece of code and see what you think it should be doing instead of what it actually is doing, especially if you wrote that code. Test/verify each piece separately until you find the part that doesn't work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code, and I think the problem is the image type.

For example, the image type JPGE is a lossy compression. Even after you cropping one part of the source image into the pattern image, the pixels at the same position will probably not have exactly the same value.

I tried two image types: JPGE and BMP. I got the result `0` from JPGE, and result `1` from BMP. In these two cases, I used the same image sample as source image (but different image type) and cropped one part of the source images into the pattern images.

The result showed that you could not match the pattern image to the valid image, but could match the pattern image to itself might be caused by the image type, which let the pattern image and valid image have image distortion and become not totally the same in the area considered should be the same.

Hope it helps.